# Javascript: Broken Link Checker - Benefits and Disadvantages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote several blog entries, which contain a table with information about 50 YouTube videos. Each of its rows consists of a thumbnail, the video title, the publishing date and a link to my internal MediaWiki for further details on the video (e.g. "http://example.com/1xC8gMecNGU").

I am planning to create a broken link checker, to display a green or red orb in the table's Wiki section, whether or not the link is available. Yet I don't know if this feature slows down my server too much and if this can be a huge flaw in DDoS attacks. Also I am unsure, if there would be a better choice than JavaScript, to decrease the CPU load.

Can you give me some tips for a page that is processing about 50 link checks?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just perform a HEAD check on each of links when the page loads? 
This way the link verification is handled by the user browser instead of your server.

Comment: Isn't a broken link checker identical to your described answer, which checks the HTTP status code (e.g. 404, 503 etc)? Basically I could use a HEAD check, but I am unsure, if there would be a better way. And before creating this, I would like to receive some recommendations and plan if this is a good concept.

Comment: Sorry from question I thought you where worried about the load on your server having to do the check. My answer was simply moving the load from your server having to do the check to the browser. Or are you checking for dead links on your site? If that is the case and you are worried about DDoS it is up to your router to handle that. Most web servers can handle 1000s of calls a second without to much trouble, but if you are expecting more than that you are going to encounter more interesting issues.

Comment: Correct. The Wiki links were created automatically, so I need to check if every link to my internal Wiki is available or not (404). My worries are that if someone tries to DDoS my page, he chooses one of my video table pages, which contain a link check and accumulate traffic on my page. And also if the user experience for about 20 guests, who visit a page for a link check, are still able to browse the page without trouble.

Comment: The problem with trying to defend against DDoS is that you can't (really). A DDoS attack doesn't care about your which address it uses, it will then can just as easily grab your main domain and spam that with calls. Hence the comment about the router handling such an attack, the router will restrict the calls to your server. As for your worry about load 20 guest won't cause havoc. It will again come down to amount of work that your webapi does when the call comes in a simple HEAD request with 404 response is going to be minimal.